# Input 7 letter word, output 7 digit phone number

Tags: c++, string, error-handling, c++14

I am writing code for an assignment. I input 7 letters and it outputs the corresponding digits on a numpad. So far it converts the letters just fine, it ignores everything past the 7th letter which is what I want and stops when you type stop. However, if I include spaces (which is required for the assignment) it throws an error, I wrote something that is supposed to make it ignore them but its not working. Also, if I input anything shorter than 7 letters I also get an error. "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at: _n (which is 1) >= this->size() (which is 1) Aborted (core dumped)

I'm pretty sure I get that it is because of the while loop, in the debugger, it always stops there but i don't know how to get around this. I look forward to hearing from anyone. Thank you in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    //declares variables
    string str1, str2;
    int i;
    //first input
    cout << "Type 'stop' to stop or type your 7 letter message to be converted to numbers: " << endl;
    cin >> str1;
    
    //while loop so that you can input multiple numbers one after the other until stop is read
    while (str1 != "stop"){
        //resets i if str1 does not equal stop
        i=0;
        while(str2.length() != 7){
            //determines what number to assign to the charcter at the index of the i variable
            if (str1.at(i) == 'a' || str1.at(i) == 'A' || str1.at(i) == 'b' || str1.at(i) == 'B' || str1.at(i) == 'c' || str1.at(i) == 'C'){
                str2 = str2 + '2';
                i=i+1;
            }else if (str1.at(i) == 'd' || str1.at(i) == 'D' || str1.at(i) == 'e' || str1.at(i) == 'E' || str1.at(i) == 'f' || str1.at(i) == 'F'){
                str2 = str2 + '3';
                i=i+1;
            }else if (str1.at(i) == 'g' || str1.at(i) == 'G' || str1.at(i) == 'h' || str1.at(i) == 'H' || str1.at(i) == 'i' || str1.at(i) == 'I'){
                str2 = str2 + '4';
                i=i+1;
            }else if (str1.at(i) == 'j' || str1.at(i) == 'J' || str1.at(i) == 'k' || str1.at(i) == 'K' || str1.at(i) == 'l' || str1.at(i) == 'L'){
                str2 = str2 + '5';
                i=i+1;
            }else if (str1.at(i) == 'm' || str1.at(i) == 'M' || str1.at(i) == 'n' || str1.at(i) == 'N' || str1.at(i) == 'o' || str1.at(i) == 'O'){
                str2 = str2 + '6';
                i=i+1;
            }else if (str1.at(i) == 'p' || str1.at(i) == 'P' || str1.at(i) == 'q' || str1.at(i) == 'Q' || str1.at(i) == 'r' || str1.at(i) == 'R'|| str1.at(i) == 's' || str1.at(i) == 'S'){
                str2 = str2 + '7';
                i=i+1;
            }else if (str1.at(i) == 't' || str1.at(i) == 'T' || str1.at(i) == 'u' || str1.at(i) == 'U' || str1.at(i) == 'v' || str1.at(i) == 'V'){
                str2 = str2 + '8';
                i=i+1;
            }else if (str1.at(i) == 'w' || str1.at(i) == 'W' || str1.at(i) == 'x' || str1.at(i) == 'X' || str1.at(i) == 'y' || str1.at(i) == 'Y'|| str1.at(i) == 'z' || str1.at(i) == 'Z'){
                str2 = str2 + '9';
                i=i+1;
            }else if(str1.at(i) == ' '){
                //if there is a space, it is ignored
                i=i+1;
            }else{
                //in case they put somthing weird, sets str2 to length of 7 to end while
                cout << "incorrect input";
                str2 = "abcdefg";
            }
        }
        //outputs converted number
        cout << str2.substr(0,3) << "-" << str2.substr(3,7) << endl << endl;
        cout << "Type 'stop' to stop or type your 7 letter message to be converted to numbers: " << endl;
        cin >> str1;
        //resets str2
        str2 = "";
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and check the length of input to avoid the errors.

Comment: `while(str2.length() != 7){` will loop until the length is 7.  Is that what you intend if the input string is less than 7 characters?

Comment: I included an if statement at the bottom that if it encounters any error inputs, to set str2 to a 7 length string to end the while loop but it doesn't work.

Comment: The getline helped with the spaces problem thank you! it now ignores spaces and outputs correctly. however, if the string is too short, I still get the error.

Comment: If i added an if statement that checked to make sure str1 has a length greater than 7, the input "a s d f " would trigger the if statement but an error would still happen because the while loop ignores the spaces.

Comment: "_Aborted (core dumped)_" - It sounds like you probably have at least two tools at your disposal to help with that. A debugger (`gdb`) and address sanitizer. Start with adding this when compiling `-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak -fstack-check -ggdb -pg -lasan -lubsan`. If just running the program doesn't tell you exactly which line the core dump happens at, run it with `gdb <program>` and step forward line by line.

Answer (score 0):

- You should use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read entire line even if it contains whitespace characters.
- You should check the length of input string and stop at the end of the string to avoid `std::out_of_range` error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    //declares variables
    string str1, str2;
    int i;
    //first input
    cout << "Type 'stop' to stop or type your 7 letter message to be converted to numbers: " << endl;
    getline(cin, str1); // *** use std::getline()
    
    //while loop so that you can input multiple numbers one after the other until stop is read
    while (str1 != "stop"){
        //resets i if str1 does not equal stop
        i=0;
        while(str2.length() != 7){
            //determines what number to assign to the charcter at the index of the i variable
            if (i >= str1.length()) { // *** length check
                cout << "input too short";
                str2 = "abcdefg";
            }else if (str1.at(i) == 'a' || str1.at(i) == 'A' || str1.at(i) == 'b' || str1.at(i) == 'B' || str1.at(i) == 'c' || str1.at(i) == 'C'){
                str2 = str2 + '2';
                i=i+1;
            // *** omit ***
            }else{
                //in case they put somthing weird, sets str2 to length of 7 to end while
                cout << "incorrect input";
                str2 = "abcdefg";
            }
        }
        //outputs converted number
        cout << str2.substr(0,3) << "-" << str2.substr(3,7) << endl << endl;
        cout << "Type 'stop' to stop or type your 7 letter message to be converted to numbers: " << endl;
        getline(cin, str1); // *** use std::getline()
        //resets str2
        str2 = "";
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked excellently thank you so much! I knew it would be a simple solution that i wasnt thinking of. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is caused by `cin`:
   `cin` considers a space (whitespace, tabs, etc) as a terminating character, which means that it can only display a single word (even if you type many words).[https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_strings_input.asp]
2. You must also change the while condition from `while(str2.length() != 7)` to `while(i != 7)` because `else if(str1.at(i) == ' ')`only increases `i` not `str2`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is the input, since cin sops the input of a string when a spacing character is encountered.  Another problem is the asumption about a minimum length which is not always fulfilled.

It's not the cause of your problem, but naming variable can help to make your code much more clearer (e.g. `input, output` instead of `str1 and str2`).  Finally, there are easier ways than long ifs to get to the right encoding:

```
int main(){
    string input, output, mapin ="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 
                          mapout="22233344455566677778889999";
    cout << "Type 'stop' to stop or type your 7 letter message to be converted to numbers: " << endl;
    
    bool input_ok=true; 
    while (cin >> input) {
        for (auto &c: input)
            c = tolower(c);    // lowercase,  just to simplify
        if (input=="stop" || output.size()==7) 
            break;              // reasons to stop reading 
        
        for (auto &c:input) {
            auto pos=mapin.find(c); 
            if (pos==string::npos) {
                input_ok=false; 
                output += '?';
            }
            else output += mapout[pos];
            if (output.size()==7)
                break;
        }
    }
    if (input_ok) {
        cout << output.substr(0,3)  ;
        if (output.size()>3) 
            cout << "-" << output.substr(3,7) ;
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "incorrect input" << endl <<output<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/wqtv3z)

For easy handling, I first convert the string to lowercase, sto that STOP, StOp or stop would all work.  Then I run several inputs, to catch several groups of letters that may be separated by spacings (blank, tabs, newline, ...).  Then for every letter, I look for its offset in an input table and I use the digit at the same offset in the output table.

Another variant is to make a calculation of the output char:

```
  for (auto &c:input) {
        if (isalpha(c)) 
            output += (c>='w'? '9' : (c>='p'? "78"[(c-'p')/4]:'2'+(c-'a')/3));
        else {
            input_ok=false; 
            output += '?';
        }
        if (output.size()==7)
            break;
    }
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/5EeKZZ)

But you could as well stick to your original version, but opting for a switch statement instead of a long cascade of ifs.